# Expanding a term with a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

We have the following quantity: $$E\left[\left(\sum^n_{j=1} (X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}))^2-t\right)^2\right]$$

My textbook says this can be expanded in the following way (colors are my touch)

$$E\left[\color{red}{\sum^n_{j=1} (X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}))^4} \\+ 2 \sum^n_{i=1} \sum_{j <i} (X(t_i) - X(t_{i-1}))^2 (X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}))^2 \color{blue}{- 2t \sum^n_{j=1} (X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}))^2}  \color{green}{+t^2}\right]$$

So if we expand $(a-b)^2$ we get $\color{red}{a^2} \color{blue}{-2ab} \color{green}{+b^2}$

So, as you can see, I have no clue where the black part comes from, and I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If you let $a = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(X(t_j) - X(t_j)\right)^2$, then $$(a - t)^2 = a^2 - 2at +t^2$$

Notice that $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a^2_i + 2 \sum_{i<j} a_ia_j$$

for example $$(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc$$

Then what is $a^2$?